# Unable to fetch the Parent Account information into the Child Account Record

Tags: apex, trigger

I have one section in Account named as Credit Information having five fields init. While creating Child Account Record, I wanted to fetch the Credit Information from Parent Account. Below is the method from Trigger & getting this error:-

> AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by:
> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
> Class.AccountTriggerHandler.UpdateCreditInfoFromParent: line 660,
> column 1 Class.AccountTriggerHandler.accountTriggerHandlerMethod: line
> 22, column 1 Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 9, column 1

Code is :

```
 public static void UpdateCreditInfoFromParent(List<Account> newAccountList, Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap){
    Map<Id, Account> mapNewAccount = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Account ac: newAccountList){
        if((ac.Account_Level__c == 'Parent' || ac.Account_Level__c == 'Account') && !ac.Exclude_Account__c && ( ac.ParentId != oldAccountMap.get(ac.Id).ParentId || Trigger.isInsert) ){
            //mapNewAccount.Put(ac.ParentId,ac);
            mapNewAccount.Put(ac.id, ac);
            parentIds.add(ac.ParentId);
            system.debug('Map New Account Else' + mapNewAccount );
        } 
        
    }
    if(mapNewAccount.size()>0){
       // List<Account> lstUpdateAccount = new List<Account>();
        //Fetch Parent Accounts using Ultimate Id
        List<Account> lstChildAccounts = [Select Id, ParentId, recordtypeId, Exclude_Account__c, Credit_Check_Date__c, Credit_Limit__c, Credit_Check_Status__c,Credit_Bureau_Link__c, Risk_Rating__c, Advance_Recommended__c, Segment__c, Industry, P23_FSU__c, Exception_Account_23F_CDU__c from Account where Id IN:parentIds ];
        Map<Id, Account> mapParentAccount = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Account childAc: lstChildAccounts){
            mapParentAccount.put(childAc.Id,childAc);   
        }
        system.debug('Map Child Account' + mapParentAccount);
        //Fetch Child Accounts Using Ultimate Id
        if(mapParentAccount.size() > 0){
            for(Account acc :mapNewAccount.values() ){
                if(mapParentAccount.containsKey(acc.ParentId)){
                    
                    Account parentAcc = mapParentAccount.get(acc.ParentId);
                    if(TESTAccountRecordType == acc.recordtypeId || TESTAccountRecordTypeLocked == acc.recordtypeId) {
                        acc.Advance_Recommended__c = parentAcc.Advance_Recommended__c;
                        acc.Credit_Bureau_Link__c = parentAcc.Credit_Bureau_Link__c;
                        acc.Credit_Check_Date__c = parentAcc.Credit_Check_Date__c;
                        acc.Credit_Check_Status__c = parentAcc.Credit_Check_Status__c;
                        acc.Credit_Limit__c = parentAcc.Credit_Limit__c;
                        acc.Risk_Rating__c = parentAcc.Risk_Rating__c;
                    }  
                }
            }   
        }
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the line no. 4 Replace this line

```
if((ac.Account_Level__c == 'Parent' || ac.Account_Level__c == 'Account') && !ac.Exclude_Account__c && ( ac.ParentId != oldAccountMap.get(ac.Id).ParentId || Trigger.isInsert) ){
```

with the below line

```
if((ac.Account_Level__c == 'Parent' || ac.Account_Level__c == 'Account') && !ac.Exclude_Account__c && (Trigger.isInsert||ac.ParentId != oldAccountMap.get(ac.Id).ParentId ) ){
```

you have to just swap the order of condition and check if it works

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved !!